# Reading temperature and fan speeds on chipset without WMI support in Windows, from Delphi

Tags: delphi

I have searched and searched but found nothing about how in Delphi, and I am using XE2 how to read sensor information from the Unvoton NCT6776F chip.  I am guessing I need some assembly somewhere but there is nothing I can find on how to even begin.  Here are the registry details of the chip.

> ```
> Bus Type = ISAIO
> One NCT6776F
>
> Unvoton NCT6776F, IndexReg=A35, DataReg=A36
> =============================================================
> Fan1 Fan Speed, Bank 6, Offset 0x30, 0x31 RPM = 1350000/(Data=HighByte[12:5], LowByte
>
> [4:0])
> Fan2 Fan Speed, Bank 6, Offset 0x32, 0x33 RPM = 1350000/(Data=HighByte[12:5], LowByte
>
> [4:0])
> Fan3 Fan Speed, Bank 6, Offset 0x34, 0x35 RPM = 1350000/(Data=HighByte[12:5], LowByte
>
> [4:0])
> CPU Voltage, Bank 0, Offset 0x20      Voltage = Data* 0.008
> VCCSA Voltage, Bank 0, Offset 0x21        Voltage = Data* 0.008
> +3.3V Voltage, Bank 0, Offset 0x22        Voltage = Data* 0.016
> Gfx Voltage, Bank 0, Offset 0x24      Voltage = Data* 0.008
> +5V Voltage, Bank 0, Offset 0x25      Voltage = Data* 0.008/ (10./40.)
> +12V Voltage, Bank 0, Offset 0x26     Voltage = Data* 0.008/ (10./66.2)
> 3.3VSB Voltage, Bank 5, Offset 0x50       Voltage = Data* 0.016
> VBAT Voltage, Bank 5, Offset 0x51     Voltage = Data* 0.016
> CPU Temperature, Bank 7, Offset 0x17, 0x18    PECI Count = (Data=HighByte,LowByte<15:6> 
>
> hightest bit as sign bit)
> High: PECI Count>-15; Midium: -40<PECI Count<=-15; Low: PECI Count<=-40
> System Temperature, Bank 0, Offset 0x27   Temperature = Data
> Peripheral Temperature, Bank 1, Offset 0x50   Temperature = Data
> Chassis Intrusion, Bank 0, Offset 0x42, BitMask 0x10  1 = Bad, 0 = Good
>           (Clear Bit: Bank 0, Offset 0x46, BitMask 0x80)
>
> Power Supply Failure, NCT6776F, Logical Device 0x0B, CRF7h, BitMask 0x01  0 = Good, 1 
>
> = Bad
> ```

If anyone has any idea how I can read these addresses and get the required information I would be very grateful.  If anyone could post some example code, that would be even better.  What I am in fact trying to do is add a Temperature sensor gauge to my server software for monitoring purposes.  I need to integrate the data directly and not use a third party application due to the nature of the application I am building.

Thanks.

Alex.

Comment: Take a look at [`this post`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1541345/960757) for instance (the 4th hit from the Related section on this page).

Comment: I am using WMI for many other functions in the application, but this one "Select * FROM Win32_TemperatureProbe" does not work.  I don't think SuperMicro have implemented it properly.  Anyway, it returns nothing when queried.  Need to find another way.

Comment: If WMI is not supported then you need to enumerate the device drivers installed on your windows system, and find a way to talk directly to the driver.  If there is no driver for this chipset, you would have to write one, which has to be done in regular C code using the windows device driver DDK.

Comment: I bump into this 'site' (http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=463&lngWId=7), it is an old codes for old board, but maybe it can give you some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information on the [lm-sensors wiki](http://www.lm-sensors.org/wiki/Devices) - the device is accessed using the LPC bus. There is a dedicated GPLed [linux driver](https://github.com/groeck/w83627ehf/archives/master) that can be downloaded to access the device under linux. I would not look at this source if I was planning on an implementation myself because of the possibility of tainting any proprietary code that is written to access the device.

In order to perform peripheral I/O using delphi (as in the `inb`/`outb` instructions or their equivalent), you should look at the question [how to write to I/O ports in Windows XP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167579/how-to-write-to-i-o-ports-in-windows-xp-delphi7)

Comment: I have had a look at using the IO.DLL, however can anyone decode which address I should be using for the CPU temp given the data above?  Offset? Bank? IndexReg?  Any ideas how to find the correct address?  Thanks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the drivers are already written for windows. However the OP does not know how to communicate with Windows driver layers, and WMI is not enabled for this particular device driver.